# Why it is recommended to declare instance variables as private?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, private, protected

My question relates to Java, but it also can be applied to C#. I was wondering why everybody recommends making the instance variables **private** as opposed to making them **protected**.

Let's just think about it. Private variables are not seen by the subclass, so if I need to access or change the variables of the superclass in my subclass I am forced to use some accessor and mutators method like `getMyPrivateVariable` or `setMyPrivateVariable`. But when you extend some class and inherit its members, this works as if you have declared them in the subclass directly. So logically this means that the subclass should also have direct access to the instance variables and makes a case for designing the class with protected variables. I understand that such a practice would break encapsulation but this seems irrelevant in the case of inheritance, because, again, in this case everything works as if the members of the superclass were declared in the sublcass, so the sublcass has a "natural right" for being able to access its members directly, no matter if they were inherited or not. Encapsulation, in my opinion, is more important for interfacing with the object by other objects that are outside of the object's inheritance tree.

So, my question is why everyone recommends declaring instance variables of the class as private as opposed to protected?

Comment: This is a question suitable for programmers.stackexchange.com rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Not _everyone_ does. But from your text it seems you got the point of `protected`; in any event, do what you feel is right.

Comment: Just because a class allows inheritance does not mean it wants to allow arbitrary corruption of its internal invariants by child classes. Making fields (and some methods) `private` allows for this.

Comment: @diev - can making the variables protected really open room for corrupting the internal data structure of the superclass by the subclass? I think, it can happen only when you make its variables publicly accessible because then literally every class will have direct access to them. But when they are protected it is essentially about the sublass being able to access its own data structure directly, because when you inherit some members it is like you have declared it by yourself.

Comment: @akhilless Absolutely not: if a field is `protected`, then it's actually implicitly `public`, since any subclass is free to create publicly accessibly methods to access it. If a class needs to maintain an invariant, `private` members are essential.

Comment: @dev yes, any subclass can create a public method to access it, but a poorly-written method would corrupt the data structure of the subclass, not  the one of the superclass, since  the badly written method could only be called via a reference to the object of the sublcass. So such a situation is a problem of the designer of the sublcass and has nothing to do with the data integrity of the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You answer it yourself - encapsulation.

For example you have an abstract Cat class.  This defines the member variable speed - i.e. how fast it's running.

The abstract class also defines a final method of run which obviously updates speed.

Now - if subclasses of Cat - e.g. Moggy or Tabby could access and modifiy "speed" directly then it could break the run method.

So best to keep it tied up where it begins.  You can also declare it locally if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

> if I need to access or change the inherited variables in my subclass I am forced to use some accessor [...]

There you have it wrong: `private` members are *not* inherited. You may be confusing the meaning of "inherit" with the fact that the instance of the subclass possesses all the members of its superclasses.

The best way to see what it means that private members are not inherited is observing that the subclass may declare its own private member, and this can never cause a clash with a superclass's private member of the same name. The two peacefully coexist.

Members are declared `protected` only when designing a class *specfically* to be used by subclassing: in this case the `protected` members are in fact a part of its public API. Most classes are *not* designed for public extension, but declaring them `final` is often not an option. If such classes had all their members `protected`, it would be tantamount to making them `public` since any client code could trivially make its dummy subclass, not adding anything to the parent, but exposing its internals.

Comment: Marko, it got me wrong. I know that private variables are not accessible by a subclass, but protected are. That's the whole point of my question - why hide the data structure of the superclass from the subclass.

Comment: You did say you want to access the inherited variables, which are not accessible; to which I reply, "they are not inherited".

Comment: I was asking about the validity of declaring the instance variables private as opposed to protected. The part you are citing says that "Private variables are not seen by the subclass", so I know they are not inherited. I have corrected the typo and I removed this word "inherited" from that place to make my line of thought more clear. On the hand, do not you think that making a dummy subclass exposing access to the inherited (protected) variables of the superclass actually exposes the internals of the sublcass, since you cannot call these methods on the object of the superclass?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following "rule of thumb": anything that is visible from outside your class becomes part of a *contract* with the outside world. In order to keep your freedom to modify your code as you wish with minimum impact, your goal is to restrict the visibility to the minimum possible -- people usually don't limit their freedom unless they're forced to.

In other words, you must have a reason to declare a member something other than `private`. Once you have a strong reason, only raise the visibility to the minimum possible extent (the first choice should be *package private* / *default* visibility). That's because you are supposed to be in full control (or at least have some control) of the code in your package, so changes there can be performed in isolation. As a side note, "package private" is the only visibility level (other than `public`) that can be applied to top level classes themselves. Therefore, you should consider removing the `public` modifier from classes that are not used outside their package.

The `protected` visibility "escapes" your range of control, since any client may rely on that particular variable or method.

As for `public`, a good practice would be to only use it for methods declared in the interfaces that you implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your instance variables protected and it's possible to subclass your class (as it's not `final`) then everybody can subclass your class and change your instance variables when you don't expect it. This raises the chance tremendously that your functionality does not behave the way you want it. You have to deal with a big variety of how your class can be used which makes it very hard for you to make sure that every possible change of your instance variables produces the expected result at any possible point in time where it is changed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's a philosophical question. But I guess it's a matter of adding a safety layer to instance variable access.

By exposing them through getters and setters, you guarantee they will be accessed correctly (no out of range values for example) regarding the role of your class. You are also preparing for future interventions, by isolating responsibilities (for example if at some point you realize some processing should be done systematically over a particular variable, then you only have one method to refine, theoretically not touching anything else and more importantly not breaking the functionality of the whole program). You have as well the liberty of defining some of them read-only, by providing only a getter method.

So basically it adds a layer of safety and gives you more control over your variables.

Moreover, since they're called instance variables, it makes sense to me that only the actual instance could access them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Essence of OOP is **sending message**, meaning favorising **behavior** over **data**.

The reason to avoid exposing your variables is to make your software the most **flexible** as possible.

Clients should not take some data from everywhere and implement logic on their own (logic that isn't part of their responsibility), they should [Tell! Don't Ask!](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).
They shouldn't master the algorithm needed, that should be the role of the targeted class.

By letting your variable `protected` in a base class (or final class..), you allow subclasses to alter them, and very very often, subclasses may not have the knowledge nor the responsibility to do that. 
It would often lead to some mysterious bugs, like assigning an unexpected value to a field's base class from subclasses. 
Of course, `protected` is needed for some cases, but only when subclasses is concerned by the very same responsibility.

Thus, always make your variable/method scope as restrictive as you can. Your code will be thus, protected, flexible, easily unit-testable (since concentrated on a single place) and exempt from many usual bugs when exposing instance variables to client. And especially, your class could change their internals without breaking client code.

Besides, avoid getters/setters when you don't deal with data structure. Indeed, this will promote behavioral methods.

Indeed, in 95% of cases, getter/setter are very poor (don't implement valuable logic), and are just an end run to make your variable `public`/`protected`.