# The reason for encapsulation

Tags: c#, private, encapsulation, public

I've read some things about this, I even found similar question, but it didn't really answer this. For me it seems that privatizing something only makes my life so much harder when I need to find a private variable in a class to use it elsewhere. So what is would the problem be if everything was public? Would it somehow slow the program itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of access modifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895101/what-is-the-purpose-of-access-modifiers)

Comment: This is off-topic on this site, but answered throughly on [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables).

Comment: Making everything public in a class essentially means your allowing everybody see and manipulate anything and everything. If something can be private make it private makes the object easier to consume.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general programming concepts. It would fit better on Programmers.SE, where [a good question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables) covering the topic is already throughly answered.

Comment: If, while you were using a calculator to do your taxes, I were to reach into the gut of the calculator and reprogram the way it did additions, or change the current number it has on the screen without you noticing, would you see that as a problem? If no, then I see your point. If yes, then there you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** consider the maintainability of the code. Accessing all the variables everywhere in your solution is good only if you are the only one in the project and you will be the only one that maintain and use the code. If someone else's entered into project and do completely different things they will be able to access your methods/variables and set the things to unexpected variables. You should think as a OOP design and design your classes like that.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I don't believe you are supposed to ask discussion-based questions like this on SO... But the simplistic answer is this: don't limit your thinking to the logic of the code. We all know there are ten thousand ways to accomplish the same thing. You can probably rewrite a bunch of your code to avoid encapsulation. However, data encapsulation provides a few benefits when you start working on larger projects or with larger teams that go beyond just writing functional code:

(1) organization by concept: if you're coding a bike you would code a class for the wheel, a class for the frame, a class for the handlebars, etc., and you'd know where to go to resolve an issue, perhaps even after months of time away from the code;

(2) separation of implementation and interface: you can tell the world about your public interface and handle the actual implementation privately, so people don't have to know how things work in your code, they just know that it works, like a black box; and if later you have to change your private implementation you can do so freely as long as the public interface still works;

(3) simplification for humans: remember, humans read your code, so would you like to slam them with every bit of data and logic in your project? that would just make for a bunch of angry programmers.

So that's a gentle introduction to encapsulation.

Comment: I did not inted to start a discussion, I just didn't know the reason behind encapsulation.

Comment: I understand, but SO is designed to answer focused questions rather than broad questions, hence the reason a bunch of people commented that this is off-topic, put your question on hold, and downvoted it.

Answer (score -1):

This comes from the fact that, a class should not expose its members directly but must provide a proxy through which the members must be accessed. (Like getters/setters or Properties)

See this question for more info: [Why it is recommended to declare instance variables as private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393736/why-it-is-recommended-to-declare-instance-variables-as-private)