# What is the point of encapsulation?

Tags: encapsulation, object-oriented-analysis

I just don't see the point of encapsulation, I see that in some cases you can modify a getter/setter to modify the behavior of something or keep track of state,  but whenever I am creating a non-conventional getter/setter, I use a word like "modify," or "obtain," so what is the point of wasting hours writing repetitive methods that are practically pointless and inefficient?

I just don't get it, when I was a wee young programmer, I was told by some guy in an IRC, that not having it was the cause for a bug in my program, but I have known for years now that is not the case, I've just been doing it anyway, so what is then point?

If I need to refactor later there are ways around it weird ones but they are ways at least in languages with overloaded operators, and API's don't always have to be backwards compatible so I don't see the point.

- Can anyone enlighten me to the necessity of encapsulation?

Comment: Seems you are not asking about the point of encapsulation (which you seem to have down pat), but the point of dogmatic faux-encapsulataion: Making all data members private but providing trivial accessors.

Comment: Have you met `std::string`? Would you like to perform all its internal operations manually, every time?

Comment: _'What Is The Point of Encapsulation'_ Keeping the code managable on a long term view.

Comment: "Can anyone enlighten me to the necessity of encapsulation?" The best enlightenment on the subject comes from well-wishing co-workers screwing around with parts of your code that you did not intend for them to see.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928327/the-reason-for-encapsulation

Comment: The point of encapsulation - done right - is managing complexity / dependencies. You need to consider the interface of a class, and without encapsulation that includes all internal details and invariants, when you use it or change it.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am considering that, as I stated when I have a data member I think may need a versatile interface I do make an encapsulated method, but I name it something so the client knows its not just returning a value. Or if I have a data member that I think may need that sort of modification in the future, I do make encapsulation for it. But for the general data member, whats the point?

Comment: How about we get into how C++ doesn't even have encapsulation!...

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit I intended to make it specifically refer to C++, and added the tags before hand, but that was a mistake. Il remove it. C++ does have encapsulation, any OOP language with methods and data members, does.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit: What?

Comment: @deviantfan There was a C++ tag, I removed it.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: I understood that, but not ResidentBiscuit´s point.

Comment: @deviantfan I did not read his whole comment, I just read the second half, and edited my response to it. My bad.

Comment: I was halfway kidding. There are common complaints about C++'s encapsulation, though, that I don't actually want to get into.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Kk, my primary language is C++, and it does seem repetitive, and I can see some reasons why that may be otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In many cases you are right - small programs doesn't need encapsulation probably.
2. Some MS infrastructures (C#/WPF I think in several binding scenarios) requires encapsulation (using properties) and will not work without it.
3. If you do more in get / set than changing the value or returning it - it will make your code nicer and more robust (do checks, or other staff in the setter for example).

No one forces you to use it anyway...